# Enum in Object literal

Tags: typescript

I've expected TheWall to be 0 within the TileSpecs literal, but it doesnt. Why and how to fix this?

```
enum Tile = {WALL, BORDER}
const TheWall: Tile = Tile.WALL;

console.log(TheWall) // Prints 0

let TileSpecs = {
  TheWall: {prop: 'value'}
}

console.log(TileSpecs) // Prints TheWall: {...}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you want `[TheWall]: {prop: 'value'}`

Comment: Yeah. In case 0: {prop: 'value'}. Thats what I've expected to be so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use your `TheWall` constant as a property name, you need to use [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax:

```
let TileSpecs = {
  [TheWall]: {prop: 'value'}
}
```

Comment: So its like the regular javascript syntax for object literals like: MyObject['string'] = 'text' or MyObject[0] = anyNumber.

Comment: @fubbe Right, computed property names use the same square bracket syntax.